# Change Window on Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

How do I change a window on Tkinter? I want to change `Login`'s window to `ListaBase`'s window, but I don't know how to make this.

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
from Tkinter import *

import tkMessageBox

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'C:\\Users\\felipe.cunha\\Documents\\project')

from conexao.conexao import Conexao


class Login(Frame):
        def __init__(self):
                Frame.__init__(self)
                #self.master = master
                self.master.title("teste")

                self.host = "localhost"
                label_menu = Label(self.master,text = 'Login')
                label_menu.pack()

                self.entrada_menu_login = Entry(self.master)# user
                self.entrada_menu_senha = Entry(self.master, show = "*")#passwd 
                self.entrada_menu_login.focus()               
                self.entrada_menu_login.pack()
                self.entrada_menu_senha.pack()

                btn_login = Button(self.master,text="Logar",command = self.btnConnection)
                btn_login.pack()


        def show_entry_fields(self):
                print(type(self.entrada_menu_login.get()), type(self.entrada_menu_senha.get()))

        def btnConnection(self):
                conn = Conexao(self.host,self.entrada_menu_login.get(),self.entrada_menu_senha.get())#,"dsti")
                self.dbCursor = conn.getConnection()


class ListaBases(Frame):
        def __init__(self,master,cursor):
                self.master = master
                #self.master.geometry("400x400")
                self.master.title("Data Bases")

                menubar = MenuBar(self.master)

                label_database = Label(self.master,text = "Lista de Banco de Dados").grid(row=1,column=0)
                #ListBox
                listBox = Listbox(self.master)
                listBox.grid(row=2,column=0)
                cursor.execute("show databases")


                for base in cursor.fetchall():
                        print base
                        listBox.insert(END,base)
                listBox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',self.selectBase)

                cursor.close()

        def selectBase(self,e):
                w = e.widget
                index = int(w.curselection()[0])
                self.value = w.get(index)
                print self.value[0]
                ListaTables(self.master,self.value[0])

class MenuBar():
        def __init__(self,master):
                self.master = master
                self.master.title("Menu Principal")
                menu_bar = Menu(self.master)
                self.master.config(menu = menu_bar)

                file_menu = Menu(menu_bar)
                file_menu.add_command(label= 'Open')
                menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=file_menu)
                menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Shell")


class ListaTables(Frame):
        def __init__(self,master,base):
                self.master = master
                self.master.title("Tables")
                cursor = Conexao("localhost","root","d04m10").getConnection()       

                cursor.execute("use %s"%(base))

                label_database = Label(self.master,text = "Lista de Tabelas").grid(row=1,column=0)
                #ListBox
                listBox = Listbox(self.master)
                listBox.grid(row=2,column=0)
                cursor.execute("show tables")


                for table in cursor.fetchall():
                        print table
                        listBox.insert(END,table[0])
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "change it to ListaBase's window"? Also, can you possibly reduce this to an MCVE?

Comment: Hello, im trying to change windows on Tkinter. My first window is login, in flux the system must go to window listabases

Comment: Destroy one and create the other.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is to put your "base" as the root window, and your login window as an instance of a Toplevel. You can hide the base window initially, or simply disable it and pop up the login window.

The other solution is to make your base window a frame, and your login window a frame. First you would pack/place/grid the login window. When the user logs in, remove the login frame and pack/place/grid the base frame.